# Using different styles of buttons to enhance the "accept" button over the "cancel" one is a good idea?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, affordance

When it comes to completing an action/form you want to highlight the "accept" button rather than the cancel.

I have seen android uses only text rather than boxing words to make them look like buttons. [image]

I have been hesitant about this approach because it goes against affordability principles.

1. Using different styles of buttons to enhance the accept button is a good idea? Or it would just make the design look messy/confusing?

[image]

2. Is option A. clean and clear? Or is it better to go with a design like B.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A more clearly outlines the main action. Cancel should be considered secondary in this case.

Generally, if a user elects to perform a task - the button to confirm the task should be more obvious.

However, in a case where where a binary choice needs to be made, like "Are you sure you want to wipe your hard drive?" Yes / No buttons should probably carry equal weight.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to think about what the effect of the different options will be.  Typically, destructive, or non-editable options are given some formatting to alert the user to this. I know you're developing with Android, but the iOS design guidelines are a useful resource to be read alongside Google's Material Design spec. On the [Action Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/) page, they state:

> **Make destructive choices prominent.** Use red for buttons that perform destructive or dangerous actions, and display these buttons at the top of an action sheet.

As the previous answer states, if the choices are non-destructive, and not a Accept / Cancel type of answer, then equal formatting is preferable.

However, its best to ask what you're hoping to achieve by presenting your users with an unfamiliar, colour-filled format. Unless there is a really specific use case, it is probably best to present your users with a familiar format. In your case of an Accept / Cancel dialog, buttons are usually unboxed, and given equal formatting, using system or app standard colour for links.

If formatting must be different, you might try giving the Accept option a coloured stroke, and keeping Cancel grey?

Comment: iOS design guidlines are quite useful, the principles they state can definitely be applied to Android designs too.